# How to Compare two arrays and its elements in visual foxpro?

Tags: arrays, visual-foxpro

I Am having two arrays named `atest` and `NEWARRAY`,I have tried to compare the elements of two arrays with simple `if()`and this is comparing only the first element of an array , how to compare all the array values at once,here's my code

```
    IF (Alltrim(atest)== Alltrim(NEWARRAY))

        Messagebox('Success',64,'Status')
    Else
        Messagebox('MisMatch',16,'Status')
    ENDIF
```

Answer (score 0):

Fox has a few functions that operate on whole arrays - like `acopy`, `ascan` and `asort` - but there is no built-in function that compares whole arrays. So you'll have to do the comparison element per element, for example with a `for` loop.

And yes, if you use an array name as an expression - including passing it by value - then you'll get the value of the first array element instead. There is one exception, though: when you pass an array to a built-in function in a place where an array parameter is expected then the compiler will automatically emit a reference token under the hood in order to arrange pass-by-reference instead of pass-by-value.

So, if you have a user-defined function `f()` to which you want to pass an array `a` then you need to call it like this: `f(@m.a)` but you can call built-in functions taking arrays like this: `alen(a)` (since the `m.` can be left off in this situation as well). In fact, Fox would complain if you coded something like `alen(@m.a)` or `alen(@a)`, and older Foxen could even crash in such situations.

Conversely, if an array is the target of an assignment like `a = 42` or `store 42 to a` then the value will be assigned to all array elements. This is convenient for initialising arrays to something like `0`, `''` or `.null.`.

Hence, if you have two arrays `a` and `b` then `a = b` will assign the first value of `b` to all elements of `a`, and `if a == b` will compare the respective first cells only.

Sidenote: should you ever have to compare records from tables with equal or equivalent structure then you should remember to look up `compobj()`. It does for objects and scatter records what Fox won't do for arrays: it compares them whole-sale. That is, it compares the values of properties with matching names and tells you if there's a mismatch, and it does so much faster than hand-crafted code could do it.

Theoretically you could gather an array into a table/cursor record and then use `scatter name Walther` to produce a scatter record, which could then be compared to a scatter record named `Herbert` that was produced in a similar fashion from the contents of the other array: `compobj(m.Walther, m.Herbert)` would tell you whether the original arrays were equal or not. However, I'd be hard pressed to imagine circumstances where one might use something like that in production code...

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple procedure like this for comparison:

```
Procedure CompareArrays(ta1, ta2)
    If Alen(ta1) != Alen(ta2)
        Return .F.
    EndIf
    Local ix
    For ix=1 to Alen(ta1)
        If (Type('ta1[m.ix]') != Type('ta2[m.ix]') or ta1[m.ix] != ta2[m.ix])
            Return .F.
        endif
    endfor
endproc
```

And pass your arrays by reference. ie:

```
isIdentical = CompareArrays(@laArr1, @laArr2)
```

If array members could hold objects, you should use compobj for comparison of array elements.